# Use send with dynamic number of arguments

Tags: ruby

I want to redirect missing methods. I have this code:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block)
  ...
  if arguments.any?
    if arguments.count == 1
      self.documentable.send(method_name, arguments.first)
    else
      self.documentable.send(method_name, arguments) # <- HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    end
  else
    self.documentable.send(method_name)
  end
  ...
end
```

When I call an undefined method on this class that has more than one argument, the method is passed to `method_missing` defined above, and I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)` because the array of arguments I pass is interpreted as one argument. How can I use `send` with a dynamic number of arguments?

Comment: You do not need any of the `self.`'s and if you are not concerned about `documentable` equalling `false`, you could write `!documentable.nil?` as just `documentable`.

Comment: I know it's not needed but it's clearer and prevents naming problems with helper or other module methods

Answer (score 5):

Use splat `self.documentable.send(method_name, *arguments)`

Comment: You might want to add that your code is to replace not just the line that the OP marked as having problem, but the entire code chunk with conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using splat (*) before your argument list.

```
irb(main):009:0> def multiple_args(name, arg1, arg2, arg3)
irb(main):010:1>   puts "arg1: #{arg1} - arg2: #{arg2} - arg3: #{arg3}"
irb(main):011:1> end
=> :multiple_args
irb(main):012:0> args = ['A', 'B', 'C']
=> ["A", "B", "C"]
irb(main):013:0> send('multiple_args', 'Davis', *args)
arg1: A - arg2: B - arg3: C
=> nil
```